# Laravel Blade view not showing passed data from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a button that will show data based on specific ID:

```
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">
  <a href="{{action('BookingController@payment', $book['booking_id'])}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Stripe Payment</a>&nbsp;        
</td>
```

The route is:

```
Route::get('payment/{id}', 'BookingController@payment')->middleware('verified');
```

The BookingController@payment is:

```
    public function payment($id)
{    
    $bookings= \App\Booking::find($id);
    return view('parking.payment')->with('bookings',$bookings);
}
```

and the blade view is:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Booking ID</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Application Status</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Semester</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Parking Area</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Parking Lot No.</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Payment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   

    @foreach($bookings as $book)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; color:red;">{{$book['booking_id']}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">{{$book['apply_status']}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">{{$book['semester']}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">{{$book['park_area']}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">{{$book['park_no']}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">{{$book['price']}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

But, the blade view only shows blank table. Is it because the data conflicts with the Stripe payment form that i make in the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$bookings = \App\Booking::find($id);` will return a single Booking, but based on your naming and the loop in the blade view it seems that you were expecting a collection. Perhaps you wanted `\App\Booking::where('booking_id', $id)->get()`? (I'm not totally clear on your database structure)